# permission in ubuntu samba file sharing

Tags: 14.04, permissions, samba

I've got a problem in my samba file sharing. I copy and paste a Microsoft word in my folder that the owner was my self and a group had access to this word by permission 750 but when I check the permission again by `ls -ld /(path to the file)` I saw something like this:

```
-rwxr-x--- +1
```

And my group didn't have any access but as I mentioned I put their access to read.

My question is can anyone tell me what is this `+`?

Answer (score 1):

It means your file has extended permissions called ACLs.

You have to run `getfacl <file>` to see the full permissions.

See [Access Control Lists](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-acls.html) for more details.

See [What is the plus (+) sign in permission in Linux ?](http://www.golinuxhub.com/2013/12/what-is-plus-sign-in-permission-in-linux.html) for more examples.

As per man page `ls`

> If the file or directory has extended security information, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '+' character.
>
> This generally means the file is encumbered with access restrictions outside of the traditional Unix permissions - likely Access Control List (ACL).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the desired configuration in the /etc/samba/smb.conf file.  Decide the permission you want and used the `create mask` option for that.  Also decide the user and group that you want the files to be when updated by your users with the `force user` and `force group` options.  I'm sure you already have specified with users you want to have access to the shared area with  the `valid users option.

This is an example:

```
[officeshared]
        comment = Office Shared Files
        path = /mnt/data/officeshared
        create mask = 0775
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        force user = officeuser
        force group = officeuser
        valid users = mary, john, phil
```